# Kinect V2 background removal track only one person

Tags: wpf, background, kinect

I am using kinectv2 for background removal. I am using the following link for my removal of background.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/758344/Background-removal-using-Kinect-green-screen-effec

Now, this code tracks all the people in the background, I only need to track only one person in the background. Could you please help me to track only one person in the background removal.

Also, I need to remove the distortion while tracking the person.

Comment: Why is it a problem that it is potentially tracking multiple people?  Will multiple people be in frame, but you want to remove all but one of them?

Comment: Yes, even though there are multiple people in the frame, I just need to display only one person with the Kinect background removal.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as altering the logic in your example to check for a specific body index value instead of any person:

```
byte player = _bodyData[depthIndex];

// Check whether this pixel belong to a human!!!
if (player != 0xff)
```

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.bodyindexframe.aspx):

> The pixel values in this frame are 8-bit unsigned integers, where 0-5 map directly to the BodyData index in the BodyFrame. Values greater than the value obtained from BodyCount indicate the pixel is part of the background, not associated with a tracked body.

If you want to look at the various BodyIndexes, the BodyBasics sample project assigns a different color to each body.  But your change could be as simple as:

```
if (player == 0)
```

But it may require a user selecting which body (0-5) to display.